# Highcharts - XAxis Label with LineFeed - how to make smaller gap?

Tags: highcharts

I have a web site where I am using the HighCharts library which is excellent - http://weather.crowe.co.nz

The charts are working properly but I want to have a X-Axis label like the following

12 and on a new line am

But I would like to control the distance that the \n creates. ie I want the am to the closer to the 12.

So my question is how can I control the vertical space between the 12 and the am? Or should I try to draw the the value manually using the highcharts drawing routines?

In case you don't see the issue the am or pm it too close to the bottom border as you can see in this image

[Sorry image not displaying so please click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi3fH.png)

Answer (score 1):

To tighten up the space between the line returns in your x-axis labels, set `useHTML: true` and then define `lineHeight` in the `style` attribute.

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan<br />here', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      style: {
        lineHeight: '120%' // set this to whatever value is needed
      }
    }
  },
```

Here's an example fiddle with this adjustment: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/anw8p884/1/

I hope this is helpful for you.

(The weather dashboard on your website is very nicely done, by the way! I particularly like how you delineated between the actual and forecast values.)